# How to swipe into a Fragment as big as the screen from a View not as big?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager

I am trying to create a main page in my android app in which there are multiple things a user can select to do. For this page, I am thinking of using a RecyclerView with a LinearLayoutManager. For each of the views in the RecyclerView (none of which are as big as the screen), I want a user to be able to swipe into a Fragment (which is as big as the screen).

I have already tried using multiple ViewPagers to solve this problem. When keeping the ViewPager as big as the screen (the default), the Fragment would be the correct size, except the view in the RecyclerView would be as big as the screen (I want it to only `wrap_content`). When shrinking the size of the ViewPager, the Fragment would not be as big as the screen, but the View in the RecyclerView would be the correct size.

I have heard that one can listen for a user's swipe on a view, except:
 - I don't know if that is what I should do in my case, and
 - I don't know how to do it for my situation

If listening for a user's swipe is the correct way to go, please give some direction and/or code on how to complete what I want to do. If it is not the way to go, please provide an alternate way.

Thanks in advance!

Update: Here is a picture describing what I mean:
[image: description]

Comment: can you draw what you want to achieve - because i don't understand what you are writing (asking for)

Comment: @ceph3us I updated the post to include a picture

Comment: view pager:  add  fragment1 - with recyclerview / add fragment2 with view ( fragment1 and 2 are items in pager adapter )

Comment: Could you please give a code sample? I'm somewhat confused

Answer (score 1):

```
// define your fragment with recycle view 
class FragmentA extends Fragment {
   // with recycler view

  // in click on recycler item method as i posted 
  // 1) do check if pager fragment exist in pager adapter 
  // 2) if not create one 
  // 3) and move to it using pager method 
}

// define second without 
class FragmentB extends Fragment {
  // without
}

// create pager 
ViewPager vp = new ViewPager(Context);
// create list with fragments for pager adapter 
// when you will swipe you will move from A to B
List<Fragment> // add FragmentA + FragmentB

// https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html
// create pager adapter - implement own or user FragmentPagerAdapter
PagerAdapter ... = new MyPagerAdapter(List<Fragment>);
// set view pager with adapter 
viewPager.setAdapter(PagerAdapter);


// add view pager to activity view - or some content view
```

> I already tried this on my own; the viewpager would not allow for the
>   correct sizes. Either the full-screen fragment size was shrunk down to
>   the size of the View in the recyclerview, or the view in the
>   recyclerview was full-screen. – Flare Cat

**its working:**

[image]

> Oh wait, read the code wrong. But still, I need to base FragmentB off
>   of what was swiped in FragmentA – Flare Cat

**solution:**

when you click on recycler item  dynamic create new fragmentB and call move to fragmentB on pager (before create new one do a check if fragment not exist already!)

or if you don't use any click on item method but just constant recycler item content create such fragments corresponding to each entry in recycler

or create some sort of map which will map each entry in recycler to to its corresponding fragment content

> As I understand it, I would need to create an onClickListener for each
>   view in the RecyclerView. But, would that onClickListener be called
>   when a user swipes the corresponding view? – Flare Cat
>
> Actually, this might work with an onTouchListener. I'll have to try it out. – Flare Cat

**once again:**

it depends what u want to achieve - if recycler is a way of brief for each fragments and you know the content and want to present each entry for recycler item counting from top to bottom then you need add those fragments one by one in same order from left to right

@FlareCat but why using pager here ? not better to open new activity or add fragment with transition on recycler item click ?

Comment: I already tried this on my own; the viewpager would not allow for the correct sizes. Either the full-screen fragment size was shrunk down to the size of the View in the recyclerview, or the view in the recyclerview was full-screen.

Comment: Oh wait, read the code wrong. But still, I need to base FragmentB off of what was swiped in FragmentA

Comment: As I understand it, I would need to create an onClickListener for each view in the RecyclerView. But, would that onClickListener be called when a user swipes the corresponding view?

Comment: Actually, this might work with an onTouchListener. I'll have to try it out.

Comment: @FlareCat but why using pager here ? not better to open new activity or add fragment with transition on recycler item click ?